# R: How to modify values of slots?

Tags: r, oop

I'm newbie in R and I have defined an object with one method called "show". In this method I modify the value of a slot and then I print to show its value. The value is correct.

**method(show)**

```
setMethod("show", "menu", function(object){
  while (TRUE){
    #Clean console
    cat("\014")
    cat("COMPARATIVA ENTRE EQUIPOS DE LA MISMA COMPETICION\n")
    cat("-------------------------------------------------\n\n")
    cat("1. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga DIA\n")
    cat("2. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga Femenina 2 - Grupo 'A'\n")
    cat("3. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga Femenina 2 - Grupo 'B'\n")
    cat("0. Salir\n\n")
    option <- readline("Selecciona opción: ")
    option <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(option))
    if (!is.na(option)){
      if (option == 1){
        object@competition <- 14
      }
      if (option == 2){
        object@competition <- 22
      }
      if (option == 3){
        object@competition <- 23
      }
      print(object@competition)
      readline("Espera ...")
      if (option == 0)
        break
    }else{
      readline("No es un número. Pulsa una tecla para introducir otra opción.")
    }
  }  
})
```

But If I try to access to the slot outside this method I've got the initial value.

```
x <- menu(competition=0, stats=0)
x
print(x@competition)
```

When I call "x" I'm calling the "show" method too and inside of them I give a value to "competition" different to 0. But, later, when I try to print the value with print(x@competition) I've got like result 0.

```
> print(x@competition)
[1] 0
```

I would like to get the value assigned inside "show" method but I've got the value when I create the object. How can I modify the value of the slot correctly?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but maybe it is similar to defining objects in the global environment from within a function, i.e. using `<<-` instead of `<-`.

Comment: Thank you @nate.edwinton but I've got an error If use <<- insted of <- inside the function when I give the value to the slot. If I use when I create the object x <<- menu(competition=0, stats=0) later I still get the the value assigned when I create the object and not the value that I assign inside show method. :(

Comment: I just added a `return(object)` statement in the function and `break` statements in the `if(... == x)`. I believe it does what you expect now, see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here are a couple of lines that helped for me:

```
myFun <- function(object) 0
setGeneric("myFun")
setClass("myClass", slots = c("competition", "stats"))
```

I then proceed with your code (slightly modified the the `setMethod`):

```
setMethod("myFun", "myClass", function(object){
  while (TRUE){
    #Clean console
    cat("\014")
    cat("COMPARATIVA ENTRE EQUIPOS DE LA MISMA COMPETICION\n")
    cat("-------------------------------------------------\n\n")
    cat("1. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga DIA\n")
    cat("2. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga Femenina 2 - Grupo 'A'\n")
    cat("3. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga Femenina 2 - Grupo 'B'\n")
    cat("0. Salir\n\n")
    option <- readline("Selecciona opción: ")
    option <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(option))
    if (!is.na(option)){
      if (option == 1){
        object@competition <- 14
        break
      }
      if (option == 2){
        object@competition <- 22
        break
      }
      if (option == 3){
        object@competition <- 23
        break
      }
      print(object@competition)
      readline("Espera ...")
      if (option == 0)
        break
    }else{
      readline("No es un número. Pulsa una tecla para introducir otra opción.")
    }
  }
return(object)  
})
```

Here is my output:

```
x <- new("myClass", competition = 0, stats = 0)
# printing just x yields:
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "competition":
[1] 0

Slot "stats":
[1] 0

# Here is what myFun(x) yields:
COMPARATIVA ENTRE EQUIPOS DE LA MISMA COMPETICION
-------------------------------------------------

1. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga DIA 
2. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga Femenina 2 - Grupo 'A'
3. Comparativa entre clubes de Liga Femenina 2 - Grupo 'B'
0. Salir

Selecciona opción:
# hits 1
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "competition":
[1] 14

Slot "stats":
[1] 0
```

Now setting `y <- myFun(x)`, we obtain (again hitting `1` in the console):

```
> print(y@competition)
[1] 14
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct and my code works equal. The problem is when I try to access to a slot outside from the method. In your test, you hit "1" in the menu and the value asigned is 14, this is correct. But If you hit "0" you will exit from menu and then If you print the value of the slot with print(x@competition) you will get 0 and not 14 like me :( I have write this before you add return(object). I'm gonna test it!!!

Comment: When setting say `y` to be `myFun(x)` I do have `14` in the `competition` slot - see above.